# Python why is it importing builtin

Tags: python, python-3.x

**`parser.py`**

```
foo = 27
```

**`bar.py`**

```
import parser
print(parser.foo)
```

This does not work because the built-in parser library is being used instead of the `parser.py` that resides in the same directory.

How do I fix this? I thought your own modules take priority when there are name clashes.

Answer (score 2):

From https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#the-module-search-path:

> When a module named `spam` is imported, the interpreter **first searches for a built-in module with that name**. If not found, it then searches for a file named `spam.py` in a list of directories given by the variable `sys.path`.

Comment: How do I ignore built-in?

Answer (score 1):

> This does not work because the built-in parser library is being used instead of the parser.py that resides in the same directory.

Use relative imports if a package, or import from file otherwise. E.g.

```
import os

# If a package, use relative import
if __package__ is not None:
    from . import parser

# Otherwise, load from file
else:
    from importlib.machinery import SourceFileLoader
    parser = SourceFileLoader(
        # Don't overwrite the sys.modules entry
        '_parser',
        os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'parser.py')
    ).load_module()
    # We don't need that anymore, cleanup
    del SourceFileLoader
```

Comment: This only works in a package scenario. If `bar` is not imported as part of a package, an `ImportError` will be thrown.

Comment: @Arnie97 Yes, you are correct. I tried doing this inside a `pyunittest` file and it was not ran as part of a package, and so didn't work.

Comment: [@Arnie97](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5072722/arnie97): Good point, thanks. Updated with a workaround for non-package.